# Twig set reusable piece of html

Tags: html, twig

I'm creating some templates with Twig and have an issue. 
I'm trying to load a piece of html that is used several times troughout a webshop. So my idea is to create a reusable piece of code that I can load everytime when needed.

The problem I'm facing is that when I do a for loop and then include that piece of code I get an empty return. With other words my code doesn't recognize the data that need to be loaded for each product in the for loop. It returns empty info boxes.

To clarify:

I have a main template index.html which calls a snippet to include some products (don't look at rain extension!!):

```
{% if featured %}

{% include 'snippets/products.rain' with {'products': featured, 'type': 'grid'} %}

{% endif %}
```

My products.rain snippet looks like this:

```
{% if type %}
{% if type == 'grid' %}
{% for product in products %} {# Products in this case = feautured products #}

<li class="item clearfix">.... etc etc .... </li>

{% endfor %}
{% elseif type == 'other-layout' %}
<div class="item">.... etc etc .... </div>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

In the for loop there's html that's for 95% the same as in each for loop. I want to place that code inside a `block` that can be included in the for loops.

So what I did was:

```
{% set product_html %}
.... a lot of html ....
<a href="{{ product.url | url }}" title="{{ product.fulltitle }}">
  <img src="{{ product.image }}" width="100" height="100" alt="{{ product.fulltitle }}"/>
</a>
{% endset %}
```

And then included in the for loop, like so:

```
{% if type %}
{% if type == 'grid' %}
{% for product in products %} {# Products in this case = feautured products #}

<li class="item clearfix">{{ product_html | raw }}</li>

{% endfor %}
{% elseif type == 'other-layout' %}
<div class="item">{{ product_html | raw }}</div>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

However this returns the html that is set however with empty `product.image` and empty `product.fulltitle`.

I tried the same with `set block`, but that has the same result.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong....??

Answer (score 4):

When you are using `{% set %}`, content inside your variable is not dynamic, it will only use data in your current context, [see it live](https://twigfiddle.com/y52b88).

You can achieve your goal using 2 ways: using [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/include.html) or using [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html).

As your piece of code for a product is small and not reused somewhere else, I suggest you to use macros:

```
{% macro product_html(product) %}
Current product is: {{ product }}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as macros %}

{% for product in products %}
  {{ macros.product_html(product) }}
{% endfor %}
```

[See it live](https://twigfiddle.com/y52b88/2)

Comment: Interesting approach with `macros`. Never thought of that.... thx! Do `macros` have any perfomance benefits against include? Or is it perhaps better to just render that html each time? Or does it actually doesn't matter what you use? I'm still learning Twig and haven't got much reference. This question I asked because I want clean code and the best/fastest performance :)